# How to use env variables from devops in JSON files within SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, azure-devops

https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-access-azure-devops-variable-in-spfx-solution-part-2/

^ From following this guide I am able to use devops environment variable groups within my SPFx app.

However, when trying to use these variables in a JSON file it just throws an error as JSON does not support variables, period.

Anyone come across this before and has the solution to use these variables in JSON files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how you do it :) - hope this helps someone!

```
// Start: Change package-solution.json to use dev ops variables
let packageSolution = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config/package-solution.json", 'utf8'));
packageSolution.solution.webApiPermissionRequests[0].resource = envVariables.APIAppregName.value;
fs.writeFileSync('./config/package-solution.json', JSON.stringify(packageSolution, null, 2));
```